# Use ask in an instance for newtype wrapped Reader

Tags: haskell

Suppose we want to have a `Worker` monad with the ability to write log strings to a file. The log file path is part of the worker `Config` available through `ReaderT`:

```
data Config = Config { logFile :: FilePath }

newtype Worker a = Worker { runWorker :: ReaderT Config IO a }
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadIO)

class (Monad m, MonadIO m) => HasLogging m where
  log :: String -> m ()
```

This is of course suboptimal in many ways. The question I'd like to ask is how to best define:

```
instance HasLogging Worker where
  log s = do
    ...
```

The thing I cannot wrap my head around is how to call `ask` to get the config. `Worker` itself does not expose `ask`. However, since it's just a newtype wrapper it should be possible to write this instance without much fuss. Or maybe not?

Comment: Why not add MonadReader to the list of things derived? You need GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, but I think you already have it in for MonadIO.  And import Control.Monad.Reader

Comment: Good point. Though, in this case I wanted to know how to write it by hand. Knew it should be easy but somehow got lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the type of the newtype constructor is

```
Worker :: ReaderT Config IO a -> Worker a
```

we can apply it on

```
ask :: ReaderT Config IO Config
```

to get

```
Worker ask :: Worker Config
```